# Is there a way to import a MS SQL .db.back (database backup) into PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, restore, import, convert

I've received MS SQL backups from a client, I'm wanting to import/restore them into a PostgreSQL environment.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have no first-hand experience. [You could try these to start](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_SQL_Server) - but if all you've got is a dump, that's just the data. If you don't also have the creation of the DB itself scripted out (the DB schema), you're kind of hosed.

/edit -

Answer (score 0):

One way of getting this to work is to download a copy of SQL Server Express, and restore the backup there. Sometimes this doesn't work, so you could try downloading a trial version of SQL Server Standard. I think it has something like a 180 day trial.

Once you got the database restored, then you can use your favorite ETL tools to move the data into PostgreSQL.